# How to use str_replace() in a loop with multidimensional arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, str-replace

I am working with three text files.......

space.txt

```
Kournikova Anna F F 6-3-1975 Red
Hingis Martina M F 4-2-1979 Green
Seles Monica H F 12-2-1973 Black
```

comma.txt

```
Abercrombie, Neil, Male, Tan, 2/13/1943
Bishop, Timothy, Male, Yellow, 4/23/1967
Kelly, Sue, Female, Pink, 7/12/1959
```

pipe.txt

```
Smith | Steve | D | M | Red | 3-3-1985
Bonk | Radek | S | M | Green | 6-3-1975
Bouillon | Francis | G | M | Blue | 6-3-1975
```

and so far I have been able to parse them all into one array. The following output is this......

```
Last_name, First_name, Middle_Initial, Gender, DOB, Fav_color
Kournikova Anna F F 6-3-1975 Red
Hingis Martina M F 4-2-1979 Green
Seles Monica H F 12-2-1973 Black
Abercrombie Neil Male Tan 2/13/1943
Bishop Timothy Male Yellow 4/23/1967
Kelly Sue Female Pink 7/12/1959
Smith Steve D M Red 3-3-1985
Bonk Radek S M Green 6-3-1975
Bouillon Francis G M Blue 6-3-1975
```

I have to replace all F's in Gender to Female, M's to Male, and the DOB format has to be "/".

Here is the following code I used to parsed the info:

```
<?php
$space_txt = './data/input/space.txt';
$comma_txt = './data/input/comma.txt';
$pipe_txt = './data/input/pipe.txt';

$parsed_space_data = file_get_contents($space_txt);
$parsed_comma_data = file_get_contents($comma_txt);
$parsed_pipe_data = file_get_contents($pipe_txt);

$space_array = myExpldeLoopFunc('space', ' ', $parsed_space_data);
$comma_array = myExpldeLoopFunc('comma', ',', $parsed_comma_data);
$pipe_array = myExpldeLoopFunc('pipe', ' | ', $parsed_pipe_data);

$finalArray = array_merge($space_array, $comma_array, $pipe_array);

function myExpldeLoopFunc($name, $sep, $data)
{
    $parsedData = explode("\r", $data);

    $arr = [];

    foreach ($parsedData as $data)  {
        $data_arr = explode($sep, $data);

        if ($name == 'space') {
            $arr[] = [
            'last_name' => $data_arr[0],
            'first_name' => $data_arr[1],
            'middle_initial' => $data_arr[2],
            'gender' => $data_arr[3],
            'date_of_birth' => $data_arr[4],
            'favorite_color' => $data_arr[5],

            ];

            if ($data_arr[3] == 'F') {
                return str_replace('F', 'Female', $arr);
            } elseif ($name == 'comma') {
                $arr[] = [
                'last_name' => $data_arr[0],
                'first_name' => $data_arr[1],
                'gender' => $data_arr[2],
                'date_of_birth' => $data_arr[3],
                'favorite_color' => $data_arr[4],

                ];
            } elseif ($name == 'pipe') {
                $arr[] = [
                'last_name' => $data_arr[0],
                'first_name' => $data_arr[1],
                'middle_initial' => $data_arr[2],
                'gender' => $data_arr[3],
                'favorite_color' => $data_arr[4],
                'date_of_birth' => $data_arr[5],

                ];
            }
        }

        return $arr;
    }
}
```

The following result deletes 'Hingis Martina M F 4-2-1979 Green' and 'Seles Monica H F 12-2-1973 Black'. What would be the best solution to replace them all?

Comment: can you show how should look the final expected array?

Comment: can you update your question to include a small sample from all your 3 files? a couple of lines from each would be great.

Comment: You are missing a `$` in line 44 ` if(data_arr[3] == 'F') {` should be ` if($data_arr[3] == 'F') {`.

Comment: you are also missing a closing bracket before `elseif($name == 'comma') {`

Comment: Question has been updated. I already tried using the $ in line 44 but it hasn't fixed the issue. The closing bracket is already there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to add two function to do the work.
One for renaming/normalizing the gender and one for normalizing the date.
And then add a call to each of the function, when you process the data value in the loop. In other words: you iterate over the values, modify them and store them in the final array.

```
function renameGender($gender)
{
    if ($gender === 'F') {
        return str_replace('F', 'Female', $gender);
    }
    if ($gender === 'M') {
        return str_replace('M', 'Male', $gender);
    }
}

function normalizeDate($date)
{
    return str_replace('-', '/', $date);
}

function myExpldeLoopFunc($name, $sep, $data)
{
    $parsedData = explode("\r", $data);

    $arr = [];

    foreach ($parsedData as $data) {

        $data_arr = explode($sep, $data);

        if ($name == 'space') {

            $arr[] = [
                "last_name"      => $data_arr[0],
                "first_name"     => $data_arr[1],
                "middle_initial" => $data_arr[2],
                "gender"         => renameGender($data_arr[3]),
                "date_of_birth"  => normalizeDate($data_arr[4]),
                "favorite_color" => $data_arr[5]
            ];

        } elseif ($name == 'comma') {

            $arr[] = [
                "last_name"      => $data_arr[0],
                "first_name"     => $data_arr[1],
                "gender"         => renameGender($data_arr[2]),
                "date_of_birth"  => normalizeDate($data_arr[3]),
                "favorite_color" => $data_arr[4]
            ];

        } elseif ($name == 'pipe') {
            $arr[] = [
                "last_name"      => $data_arr[0],
                "first_name"     => $data_arr[1],
                "middle_initial" => $data_arr[2],
                "gender"         => renameGender($data_arr[3]),
                "favorite_color" => $data_arr[4],
                "date_of_birth"  => normalizeDate($data_arr[5])
            ];
        }
    }

    return $arr;
}
```

Comment: I really don't understand. So far I did a loop using `for ($i=0; $i < count($finalArray); $i++) {


echo join(' ',  $finalArray[$i]) . '<br>';
` but where do I add the callbacks?

Comment: The for loop is not in the code you posted. That's probably the part of the code you are using to output the final array. | What i posted is only the main loop `myExpldeLoopFunc`. It uses `foreach` and loops over the data of the input array (`$data`). Basically, you are inserting the `$data_arr` elements into `$arr` and then return it, right? Now, while doing that, the normalizing/rename functions are called to alter the value and then insert it. It's just a step in between. So, in the end: `$arr` should contain the normalized and renamed values - ready for output.

Comment: I'm glad i could help :)